# How to use JavaScript to jump to the URL after the input box is sent, and the input box can still contain the keywords just entered?

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have a requirement that after entering a keyword ~ ​​the keyword will be placed at the end of a set of URLs as a parameter, and the set will redirect to the specified page to appear. But what I hope to achieve is that even if I jump to another page, the keyword I just entered will not disappear, and it will still stay in the input input box! The following is my current writing method, but it failed~ It seems that the last jump should be changed The parameters behind the URL are extracted and placed in the input box. But I am a novice in programming and I don’t know how to rewrite it to achieve it. I hope I can get your help, thank you

```js
$("#js-search").on('click',function(){
   let keyword = $("#keyword").val()
// Here, the entered keywords will be placed after the URL to jump to the specified page
     window.location.href = `/help_center?keyword=${keyword}`;
   $("#keyword").val(keyword)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="keyword">
<button id="js-search">send</button>
```

Comment: I can't tell if it would fix the problem, but it could help to use `URLSearchParams` to encode the text in the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, Once you have redirected the user to another page, You are actually sending them to a different page you will no longer have access to the current page's DOM.

If your question is **How to read the passed query param in redirected page?** then you use the following code:

```js
// ?keyword=hello
const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
const keyword = params.get("keyword"); //hello
```

If you actually updating the current page with the query parameter, Then you can follow the below code:

```
$("#js-search").on('click',function(){
   const keyword = $("#keyword").val();
   window.location.href = `?keyword=${keyword}`; // Updating the query param
});

// Setting updated query param
const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
$("#keyword").val(params.get("keyword"));
```